# How to keep PlaceHolderPageTitle without removing them when prompt with 'The page has one or more <asp:Content> controls...'

Tags: 2007, master-page, user-controls

I have the following error prompted when opening a aspx page in SharePoint Design view

```
The page has one or more <asp:Content> controls that do not correspond with <asp:ContentPlaceHolder> controls in the Master Page.

Attach a different Master Page, or change the mapping of the content regions, or correct the problem in Code View:

  - PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea
  - PlaceHolderPageTitle
```

Are there any option(s) or solution(s) that I can modify the aspx file without removing the **PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea** and **PlaceHolderPageTitle**? (because currently, I remove these two in order to view the Design view but I still need these two in my aspx)

**Update**

If I did not remember wrongly, I think I need to include both of them in my master page (do correct me if I am wrong) However, I do not wish to have so much master page for each individual page. So, I was wondering if there are any work-around or solution to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I notice that there are two **PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea** and two **PlaceHolderPageTitle**.

By removing the duplicated one, the problem will be solved.